# Why highest priority operation [ ] is not evaluated first ini = i + arr[i++] + arr[i++]?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, operator-precedence

[ ] priority is highest (anyway is higher than +). But in RHS of expression below *the first (leftmost) summand (i) is evaluated before the second summand arr1[i++]*, because i++ of arr1[i++] does not influence value of the first (leftmost) summand (i which is 1 and not changed).

I cannot strictly explain why higher priority [ ] is not evaluated first.

```
int[] arr = { 0, 0, 0 };
int i = 1;
i = i + arr[i++] + arr[i++];
System.out.println(i); // output is zero
```

Comment: I would be very wary of code written this way.

Comment: Why would you write such unreadable code?    Check your assumptions.  The JVM knows what it's doing.

Comment: How do you know the operations are done in a particular order? Let's see the contents of the arrays and the final value of `i`

Comment: it is a certification question. I care about my understanding. Sure I would never write such code...

Comment: This is why certifications are meaningless.

Comment: I would hope this certification question has an answer like `z) Just don't do this -- ever.`

Comment: @Bohemian Maybe I am mistaken. My question is about "What is the exact order of operations and why?"

Comment: @inqi777 no that was not your question. Your question was *why `[]` is not evaluated first*.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://ideone.com/Ytx9Ab) on Ideone.

Comment: FYI:  There's no way the output in your example can be zero.  `i` is non-zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See jls [Evaluate Operands before Operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2):

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an
>   operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to
>   be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is
>   performed.

and [Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1)

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully
>   evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

The most left operand is evaluated as `1` before `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

This behaves how I'd expect it to, frankly.  The operator precedence seems correct.

Given this sample code, we would expect the result to *not* be negative.

```
int[] arr = {-1000, 100, 150};
int i = 1;
i = i + arr[i++] + arr[i--];
System.out.println(i);
```

Here's what happens.

- `+` associates right-to-left, but it has a lower priority than `[]`, so it is not invoked yet.
- `arr[i++]` resolves first, and results in `100`, with `i == 2`.
- `arr[i--]` resolves next, and results in `150`, with `i == 1`.
- `+` resolves next, left to right, and adds `150 + 100 + 1`.
- The answer then becomes **251**.

So, to answer your question...yes, the array access *is* happening first.

Comment: Please see example I added to the post...

Comment: For your example, the output is 1.  I'm not sure where you got mixed up on *that* one...